# How to remove top and bottom paddign properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Do you understand why the section .search has top,left,right,bottom padding and how to remove it? The top and bottom padding should be because of Bootstrap defaults, but the top and down padding?

This seems to work:

*{
margin:0 !important; padding:0 !important

But its corret to do?

The example is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/wqg4csL0/

Html

```
<section class="search">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <form action="/signup" method="post">
      <div class="">
        <p class="col-xs-10">
          <input type="text"  name="first_name">
        </p>
        <p class="col-xs-2">
          <input  type="button" value="Search   "></input>
      </p>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>

</section>
```

CSS

```
.search{
  background-color: green;

}

 h1{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.85em;
  }

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

*, *:before, *:after  {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

[class*="col-"]{
  padding: 0 !important;
}

input,textarea,select{
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: In your example, I don't see any padding in the `.search` class

Comment: First, in your example I also can not see any padding. Second, `<input />` has no closing tag like you have `</input>`. And please avoid using `!important`. If you want to override the margin, add a class to your `col-` definition like `no-margins` and define it.

Answer (score 0):

Those margins come from the browser's default CSS. Using a [reset CSS](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) is actually common and a perfectly valid solution.

Comment: Doesn't bootstrap have a built in reset?

Comment: Thanks,but in the example it is already the normalizer.css. Its ok to add more resets?